# Why do beings, even in lower/hell realms, like their lives?

Tags: rebirth, texts, sutras, suttas, realms

As to Lord Buddha [beings suffer because they were born](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.002.than.html):

> Jaathi pachchaya jara marana soka paridewa dukka domanassa upayasa sambhawanthi
>
> From birth as a requisite condition, then aging & death, sorrow, lamentation, pain, distress, & despair come into play.

---

It is understandable why beings in the higher realms like their lives; but is there an explanation for why beings in very lower realms (like hell) like their lives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yayam tanha ponobbhavika nandiragasahagata tatratatrabhinandini, seyyathidam, kamatanha bhavatanha vibhavatanha

It is this craving(tanha) which produces re-existence and re-becoming (Punobbhava) and which is bound up with passionate greed’ (Nandi raga sahagatha) and which finds fresh **desire now here and there (tatratatrabhinandini)** namely (1) thirst for sense-pleasures (kama tanha) (2) craving for existence and becoming (bhava-tanha) and (3) craving for nonexistence, self annihilation (Vibhava tanha)

Answer (score 2):

Due to past fabrication - in order for consciousness to arise relevant faculties and body and mind gets created, or in other words to house consciousness the body and mind is created with relevant faculties tied to the particular consciousness. Your faculties will be such that you sense and perceive things differently than being in other realms. (A Deva may look down upon humans but are we disgusted of ourselves, perhaps this can be generalised to realms below as as well.) Regardless of what level of life form you are if you perceive a threat to your existance through external stimuli you react to preserve your self. The pain of losing life or death is above all else as even in these realms the notion of "I am", "myself", "my life", etc. exist.

Interesting in Asannasatta Brahma-loka, which is actually a higher plane, you do not cling to life or have love for life. 1st act of Karam performed in new being reborn is cling to the plane. (Bhavanikanthika lobha-javanas) In the Asannasatta Brahma-loka this does not happen. Any other place you love life because you cling to the plane regardless it is low or high. More on this is covered in: Abhidhamma for the Beginner by Egerton C Baptist, page 103.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that they have a sense of karmic justice in a lower or hell realm.

Comment: Hi Stephen and welcome to Buddhism SE:) Could you elaborate a bit on your answer? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Is this refuring to Buddha teachings or just a thought concieved by you,for anyone to reply? 
Life on Earth is a lower realm and can be a hell to some.Evil beings do not like being stuck in lower realms.The only beings who enjoy the lower realms are beings like Buddah and many others who enjoy helping all beings good and bad advance spiritual and on to a higher realm.

Comment: Brother, Lord Buddha never enjoyed hell at any given time, In fact Lord Buddha asked to keep away from it.And this question is not my version of anything i have mentioned text from Pali canon.

Comment: I did not say Buddha enjoyed hell,I refered to his time on Earth.